# Buffo write to net.Conn blocks permanently

Tags: go, tcp, race-condition

I'm working on a project in which I have a writeHandler which waits for incoming data on a channel and then writes that data with a buffo writer to a tcp conn. For some reason the program freezes because the go writeHandler routine blocks permanently. Interestingly it only freezes if the write request are pushed without a delay. If I add a 1 Millsec delay the issue does not occur anymore. I've already checked with the race detector but it doesn't detect anything or return any errors. Does somebody have an idea what else it could be?

WriteHandler:

```
// clientWriteRequestHandler handles all write request to clients
func (cache Cache)clientWriteRequestHandler() error {
    for {
        select {
        case writeRequest := <-cache.clientWriteRequestCh:
            if err := util.WriteFrame(writeRequest.receivingClient, writeRequest.data); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WriteFrame:

```
func WriteFrame(writer *bufio.Writer, data []byte) error {
    dataLen := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(dataLen, uint64(len(data)))
    _, err := writer.Write(dataLen)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = writer.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    writer.Flush()
    return nil
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    1 @ 0x1075565 0x10ab91d 0x12712b0 0x10af3a1
#   0x10ab91c   os/signal.signal_recv+0x9c  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:144
#   0x12712af   os/signal.loop+0x2f     /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23

1 @ 0x107b3a5 0x10476ca 0x1047415 0x1294845 0x12966f7 0x10af3a1
#   0x1294844   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.CacheHandler+0x324  /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:83
#   0x12966f6   remoteCacheToGo/cache.New.func1+0x56        /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:238

1 @ 0x107b3a5 0x10476ca 0x1047415 0x1295665 0x12954ab 0x1296575 0x10af3a1
#   0x1295664   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.AddValByKey+0x7e4           /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:252
#   0x12954aa   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.clientHandler+0x62a         /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:143
#   0x1296574   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.RemoteConnHandler.func1+0x74    /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:166

1 @ 0x107b3a5 0x107435b 0x10a9c15 0x1150266 0x1151ff5 0x1151fbb 0x119d366 0x11af88c 0x11d6bdd 0x1293f77 0x1296073 0x1296797 0x10af3a1
#   0x10a9c14   internal/poll.runtime_pollWait+0x54             /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:222
#   0x1150265   internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait+0xe5             /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87
#   0x1151ff4   internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitWrite+0x354           /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:96
#   0x1151fba   internal/poll.(*FD).Write+0x31a                 /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:275
#   0x119d365   net.(*netFD).Write+0x65                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:73
#   0x11af88b   net.(*conn).Write+0xeb                      /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:194
#   0x11d6bdc   bufio.(*Writer).Flush+0x13c                 /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:607
#   0x1293f76   remoteCacheToGo/pkg/util.WriteFrame+0x216           /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/pkg/util/util.go:58
#   0x1296072   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.clientWriteRequestHandler+0x152 /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:185
#   0x1296796   remoteCacheToGo/cache.New.func2+0x56                /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:241

1 @ 0x107b3a5 0x107435b 0x10a9c15 0x1150266 0x11529be 0x1152984 0x119e798 0x11ba3b0 0x11b87ee 0x1295e7c 0x1296be5 0x107afa9 0x10af3a1
#   0x10a9c14   internal/poll.runtime_pollWait+0x54         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:222
#   0x1150265   internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait+0xe5         /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:87
#   0x11529bd   internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead+0x2fd        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:92
#   0x1152983   internal/poll.(*FD).Accept+0x2c3            /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:394
#   0x119e797   net.(*netFD).accept+0x57                /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:172
#   0x11ba3af   net.(*TCPListener).accept+0x4f              /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:139
#   0x11b87ed   net.(*TCPListener).Accept+0x8d              /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:261
#   0x1295e7b   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.RemoteConnHandler+0x1bb /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:161
#   0x1296be4   main.main+0x404                     /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/test/remoteCacheInstanceTest.go:24
#   0x107afa8   runtime.main+0x208                  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204

1 @ 0x10a985d 0x1265608 0x126534a 0x12611e2 0x1296668 0x10af3a1
#   0x10a985c   runtime/pprof.runtime_goroutineProfileWithLabels+0x5c           /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mprof.go:716
#   0x1265607   runtime/pprof.writeRuntimeProfile+0x107                 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:724
#   0x1265349   runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine+0xc9                   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:684
#   0x12611e1   runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo+0x521                  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:331
#   0x1296667   remoteCacheToGo/cache.Cache.clientWriteRequestHandler.func1+0xa7    /Users/luickklippel/Documents/projekte/go/src/remoteCacheToGo/cache/cache.go:178
```

Comment: First, why you are using a select with one case inside the infinite loop? if there are no other cases, it is better to just wait on the channel to receive data. Second, you are returning an error inside the loop, if `writeFrame` function returns an error, doesn't it breaks the for loop and the whole `clientWriteRequestHandler` stop working?

Comment: u're right the select statement is a left over.... The error returns and the routine ends, thus the error gets passed to the call of the routine and printed... (but there is no exception..).

Comment: Where _exactly_ is it blocked? Get the full stack trace to see what might be blocking the underlying write operations.

Comment: there is no stack trace it blocks somewhere inside the WriteFrame function but I don't know where

Comment: No, it's not going to print a stack trace on it's own, you need to get that yourself. Crash the app when it's blocked, send a SIGQUIT, or setup some other handler to do this.

Comment: ok, thx for the tip. I put the stack trace in the question

Comment: So from what I can read it hangs at the writer.flush(). But why would it do that?

Comment: Flush is where a write is forced on the actual socket. Are you certain the remote side of the connection is keeping up? The write will block if all the buffers and tcp window have been filled.

Comment: mh, I've played round with the buffer size and that did not influence the behavior in any way. Also, there is basically no processing happening or anything that could cause that buffer to be full... any other idea?

Comment: The buffer size is only for efficiency, it is not to prevent blocking indefinitely. If the remote connection is ready to receive, then this may just be a symptom of some other issue. Just a wild guess, but perhaps you're locking up the whole runtime. Is there a CPU core running at 100% when this is blocked?